# Linq group by clause with eager loading

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by, include

I have deviceStatus linked to devices:

```
public class Device
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class DeviceStatus
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [...]
    public Device Device { get; set; }
}
```

How to get with Linq:

1. linked object Device of each status
2. the status with the last timestamp of each device.

For performance purpose I can have only one single request to the database.

To have linked devices of device status: I do the following request:

```
var statusMac =
    from status in actiContext.DeviceStatus.OfType<DeviceStatus>().Include(s => s.Device)
    where status.Device.Mac == mac 
    select status 
    ;
```

With this command each status has its device: `status.Device != null`

To have grouped elements by device id and get the last status, I use the group by command:

```
var lastStatusMac =
    from status in statusMac
    group status by status.Device.Id
    into g
    select g.Where(s1 => s1.TimeStamp == g.Max(s2 => s2.TimeStamp));
```

I have the last status but I lose the devices in the results. For each status : `status.Device == null`

If I add toList() it works:

```
var lastStatusMac =
    from status in statusMac**.toList()**
    group status by status.Device.Id
    into g
    select g.Where(s1 => s1.TimeStamp == g.Max(s2 => s2.TimeStamp));
```

The problem is I know toList() performs a request that brings all status to my application, and it will give some disastrous performances.

So.. how to do it in order to have one single request sent to the database ?

Comment: Do you need to return `DeviceStatus` class or you can return anonymous object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following query (`q2`) will return `DeviceStatus` that includes `Device` property. It will sent single request to database, tested in EF 6.1.3.

```
var q1 = from d in ctx.Device
         join s in ctx.DeviceStatus on d.Id equals s.Device.Id into s1
         let stat = s1.OrderByDescending(x => x.Timestamp).FirstOrDefault()
         where stat != null
         select stat.Id;

var q2 = from d in ctx.DeviceStatus.Include(x => x.Device)
         where q1.Contains(d.Id)
         select d;
```